# android and servlet communicattion using servlets

Tags: android, sockets

Im new to socket Programing and i am developing a program for my android app running on a phone to communicate with my serlet based on my machine.
Im getting an exception saying socket is closed.
the servletside

```
 private ServerSocket serverSocket;
   public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
Socket socket=null; 
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        InputStream is =socket.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis =new DataInputStream(is); 
         String input = dis.readUTF();
        data1 = dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println(input+"            "+data1);
      OutputStream dout=socket.getOutputStream();
      DataOutputStream dat = new DataOutputStream(dout);
      dat.writeUTF("Hello to you too");
      dat.close();
```

the app side

```
private Socket socket;
     private static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;
     private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.8";
 InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                        DataOutputStream out1 = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        out1.writeUTF(ip);
                        out1.writeUTF(mac);
                     out1.close();
                     Log.d("Message","WTF");
                        InputStream is =socket.getInputStream();
                        DataInputStream dis =new DataInputStream(is); 
                        while(dis.available()==0);
                       Log.d("Message","came here 2");
                       String WTF = dis.readUTF();
                       dis.close();
                       Log.d("Message",WTF);
```

Comment: You should tell more what is happening and which statements are executed before the exception comes. Please post the logcat. You should also tell which statement exactly provokes the execption. You did not tell if the server correctly receives ip and mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put on the Manifest the next  line;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>